# Is it possible for a task scheduler to use threads from a task executor?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, weblogic12c, spring-websocket

I'm using the spring websocket stomp library and I want to configure an heartbeat. In order to do so the library asks for a task scheduler instance to work, but in my application I should stick to a weblogic workmanager that I get like this:

```
@Bean(name = "wlExecutor", destroyMethod = "")
    public Executor wlExecutor() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        factory.setJndiName("java:global/comp/env/wm/default");
        factory.setProxyInterface(Executor.class);
        factory.setLookupOnStartup(true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (Executor)factory.getObject();
    }
```

While the library wants:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
            config.enableSimpleBroker("/endpoint1")
                .setTaskScheduler(<what I put here?>).setHeartbeatValue(new long[] {5000,5000});
```

Is it possible to get a task scheduler from it? Or is there any way to instantiate a simple task executor limiting threads to 1?

Comment: You can always create a `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` of size 1. If you are on a JEE server you can simply use the `DefaultManagedTaskScheduler` which is both a `TaskScheduler` and a `TaskExecutor`. It does a lookup for the JEE7 `ManagedExecutorService` (the `WorkManager` API has been deprecated long ago already but I suspect is still there for backwards compatibility).

Comment: That looks great! Could you please provide any example of injecting both of them? I'm using weblogic 12.1 so I think both of the options for the managed schedulers are available so I see no reason to use something that is old already

Comment: Instead of the `@Bean`  you have now, replace it with a `DefaultManagedTaskScheduler` and make that also the return type of the method. Assuming you want to use the default as specified in JEE7, that is all you need. Then you can just `@Autowire` a `TaskScheduler` in your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: So I just do "return new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler" in the method body? But how to link it with the jndi name? And what happens to this code if I perform it in a normal spring boot application?

Comment: There is a default JNDI name, else just set it to what you want (there is still a setter just like your other bean). Also not sure what you mean with what happens in a normal spring boto applciation? The same as what would happen with your own `@Bean` it will probably blow up as there is no JNDI or element registered.